# SLACK API ) how can i get TimeStamp in Message Url?

Tags: python, slack

i want to make command like '/deleteMessage (URL)'
so i tried to use SlackAPI-[chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete)

but it needs timestamp, no url

how can i convert url to timestamp ?

so, i want this

input >> url of message

output >> timestamp of message

Answer (score 4):

The digits at the end of a Slack message URL is the timestamp of the message. You'll need to add a period six digits from the right and you can use this to delete your message via `chat.delete`.

As an example, for this URL: `https://your-own-workspace.slack.com/archives/CA912334S/p1675234624350123`.

The timestamp would be `1675234624.350123`.